# Функция fsockopen перестала работать с ssl

Tags: php, centos, ssl, openssl

На vps (CentOS 7) перестала работать функция fsockopen с протоколом ssl:

```
fsockopen('ssl://smtp.yandex.ru', 465, $errnum, $errstr, 5);
```

Результат возвращает **false**, **$errnum** = 0, **$errstr** = ''. С другими протоколами проблем нет. Месяц назад работало, за месяц много что настраивал на vps, теперь не могу определить проблему. В лог ошибок попадает следующее:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  fsockopen():
SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in /site/fsockopen.php on line 3
PHP message: PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto in /site/fsockopen.php on line 3
PHP message: PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.yandex.ru:465 (Unknown error) in /site/fsockopen.php on line 3"
```

Comment: а что возвращает $errnum ? есть ли ошибка ?

Comment: @Arsen, в тексте добавил

Comment: А это произошло после того как вы прикрутили PHP как FastCGI,Или он у вас всегда был  ?

Comment: @Vanya был и работал раньше

Comment: может очень глупо прозвучит, а сам сертификат проверили?) срок и т.п. не прошел

Comment: Прочитай тут ,парень описывает решение похожих ситуаций  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fsockopen.php#115405 

А это пошаговое решение ваших проблем http://neurotechnics.com/blog/ssl-ca-bundles-for-curl-and-php/ 
Если внимательно прочитаете и сделаете как советуется то будет вам успех

Comment: И тут тоже http://stackoverflow.com/a/32366242/6120970

Comment: интереса ради, а попробуйте tls://
может сработает?

Comment: А куда-нибудь еще по SSL соединяется?
`fsockopen('ssl://google.com', 443, $errnum, $errstr, 5);` например. Что-бы понять это со всеми сертификатами или как.

Comment: @Руслан нет, тоже не работает

Comment: @chernomyrdin нет, тоже такая же ошибка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всем спасибо, кто помогал, проблему решил следующим образом:

1. Скачал сертификат от сюда: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem и
   положил его в каталог `/etc/ssl/certs/`
2. В `php.ini` прописал: `openssl.cafile=/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem`
3. Выставил стандартные права на каталог `/etc/pki/`, так как в данной системе    `/pki/tls/certs/` смонтировано на `/etc/ssl/certs/` (не
   хватало прав чтобы прочитать    сертификат, это видимо одна из
   основных проблем которую я не замечал, по ошибке
   неправильные права выставил на `/etc/pki/` когда что то делал на сервере)

Comment: Схожая ситуация случается когда в Ubuntu/Debian удаляешь пакет `ca-certificates`. Удаляются все корневые сертификаты, которыми пользуются все кто работает через openssl